# Read data from excel sheet in php

Tags: php

I am using this code for reading data from any file but if i want to read data from excel sheet then what should i do?

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $cir="certificate";
      if(!is_dir($cir)){
           mkdir($cir);
      }
      $image1=$_FILES['cir']['name'];
      $image=$_FILES['cir']['tmp_name'];
      $server_path=$cir.'/'.basename($_FILES['cir']['name']);
      $s=move_uploaded_file($image,$server_path);
     if($s){
        //echo "successfully uploaded.";
        $file_open=fopen("$cir/$image1","r");
        $file_read=fread($file_open,filesize("$cir/$image1"));
        echo $file_read;
        //$data = substr(strrchr("$cir/$file_read", ","),5 );
        echo $file_read;
     }else{
        echo "problem in uploading.";
     }
   }
?>
<html>
     <body>
         <form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <input type="file" name="cir" /><br />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Excel sheet containing various shells like Name-XYZ, s.no-123 etc. I want that xyz should be put on a variable and 123 should be on another variable. What will be code in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site involves reading excel files extensively then go for a library like https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel . It supports both xls and xlsx types.

Comment: actually it doesn't read/write xslx file types. for those types is better PHPExcel

Comment: Yes (as I said). For reading purpose mentioned lib is good as PHPExcel is heavier just for reading purpose. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library for same.